# Duplicate IIS web site with Web Deploy

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, web, deployment

I have a Win2008 server with IIS 7 and I want to duplicate one web site and just change the binding port and the application pool that is using, so I will have 2 web sites (locally or remote) with same configuration but listening on different ports.

Is there a way to do this with web deploy tool ir order to deploy locally and remotely this unique web site and change the binding ports in the destination?

Answer (score 0):

I found another question that answers exactly what I need. I just made some adjusments to my scenario:

[IIS7 - Web Deployment Tool - SetParam/SetParamFile to set http and https bindings + Cert](https://serverfault.com/questions/110661/iis7-web-deployment-tool-setparam-setparamfile-to-set-http-and-https-binding)

Now I can set the parameters in the command line like this:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync
     -source:package=machinename.zip
     -dest:appHostConfig=NewSiteName,computername=webserver1
     -setParam:name=SiteA-http,value=*:8080:
```

and just change the "webserver1" and "8080" with what I need.